# Troubleshooting wires and fusable links in '96 Dodge Dakota 4 cyl. 5 speed manual

Tags: electrical

On the AC compressor, what wire is hot?  Black with white stripe or solid black?

Answer (score 3):

Solid black is your ground. That's standard on most vehicles, and certainly on Dodge/Chrysler/Jeep.

Comment: Now that it's wired in right the a.c. clutch is kicking on and when the radiator fan kicks on and off the a.c. clutch starts to sync itself to actions of the radiator fan. Why ? How do I troubleshoot this problem???

Comment: The radiator fan operates when the a/c compressor is operation to keep the condenser coil from overheating. This is not a issue it is normal operation. The radiator  fan also kicks in when the engine coolant thermostat activates the relay.